I am trying to write a PowerShell1 file that when ran will open one window with two tabs pointing to 2 different network folders
Here is what I tried, but it will open two separate folders and not one folder with two tabs open:
PowerShell:
# Set the desired folder paths
$folder1 = "\\network folder 1"
$folder2 = "\\network folder 2"

# Create a new Explorer window
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# Open the first tab
$folder1Item = $shell.Namespace($folder1)
$folder1Window = $folder1Item.ParseName("")
$folder1Window.InvokeVerb("Open")

# Open the second tab
$folder2Item = $shell.Namespace($folder2)
$folder2Window = $folder2Item.ParseName("")
$folder2Window.InvokeVerb("Open")

# Set the focus to the first tab
$folder1Window.Activate()


Would be too easy if explorer.exe offered command line parameter to open path URL to an already opened explorer.exe instance.


Save code somewhere with somename.ps1
Edit $preloadedPaths list to suit your own needs, or remove them all
right click on somename.ps1 and select "Run with PowerShell"

Once form is opened, select additional folders(you can pick exe also, or mod to your needs), or if you have own list, pick cmd or powershell. It will open each path in own tab.

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class IconExtractor {
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int ExtractIconEx(string lpszFile, int nIconIndex, IntPtr[] phiconLarge, IntPtr[] phiconSmall, uint nIcons);
}
"@

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$iconPath = "C:\Windows\System32\pifmgr.dll"
$iconIndex = 4
$iconHandle = New-Object IntPtr[] 1
$result = [IconExtractor]::ExtractIconEx($iconPath, $iconIndex, $iconHandle, $null, 1)

if ($result -gt 0 -and $iconHandle[0] -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
    $form.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle($iconHandle[0])
} else {
    $errorCode = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()
    Write-Host "Failed to load icon. Error code: $errorCode"
}
$form.Text = "Open Paths or Executable Locations in CMD/PowerShell"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(500, 350)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'Sizable'

$listBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(450, 180)
$listBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20, 20)
$listBox.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left

$btnAddPath = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnAddPath.Text = "Add Folder Path"
$btnAddPath.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(225, 30)
$btnAddPath.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20, 210)
$btnAddPath.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left

$btnSelectApp = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnSelectApp.Text = "Select Executable"
$btnSelectApp.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(225, 30)
$btnSelectApp.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(245, 210)
$btnSelectApp.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left

$btnOpenCmd = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOpenCmd.Text = "Open in CMD"
$btnOpenCmd.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(160, 30)
$btnOpenCmd.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(150, 260)
$btnOpenCmd.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left

$btnOpenPowershell = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOpenPowershell.Text = "Open in PowerShell"
$btnOpenPowershell.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(160, 30)
$btnOpenPowershell.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(310, 260)
$btnOpenPowershell.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right

$btnCancel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$btnCancel.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20, 260)
$btnCancel.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left
$pwsh = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$preloadedPaths = @(
    "C:\Program Files",
    "C:\_Progs\cpuz_x64.exe",
    "C:\Windows",
    "\\myServerName\c$",
    "\\myServerName\Tutorial",
    "\\myServerName\Tutorial\OvoOno.txt"
)
foreach ($path in $preloadedPaths) {
    if (Test-Path $path) {
        $listBox.Items.Add($path)
    }
}
$btnAddPath.Add_Click({
    $folderBrowser = New-Object Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folderBrowser.Description = "Select Folder Path"
    if ($folderBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $selectedPath = $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
        $listBox.Items.Add($selectedPath)
    }
})

$btnSelectApp.Add_Click({
    $fileDialog = New-Object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileDialog.Title = "Select Executable"
    $fileDialog.InitialDirectory = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
    $fileDialog.Filter = "Executables (*.exe)|*.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    if ($fileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $selectedFile = $fileDialog.FileName
        $listBox.Items.Add($selectedFile)
    }
})

$btnOpenCmd.Add_Click({
    if ($listBox.Items.Count -eq 0) {
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select at least one path or executable.", "Error", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }    
    $commands = @()
    foreach ($item in $listBox.Items) {
        $name = Split-Path $item -Leaf
        if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) {
            if ($item.StartsWith("c:\*") -or $item -like "C:\*") {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$name`" cmd /k cd `"$item`""
            } else {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$item`" cmd /k `"pushd $item`""
            }
        } elseif (Test-Path $item -PathType Leaf) {
            $folder = Split-Path $item
            $escapedItem = "`"" + $folder + "`""
            
            if ($folder.StartsWith("c:\*") -or $item -like "C:\*") {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$name`" cmd /k cd `"$escapedItem`""
            } else {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$name`" cmd /k `"" + "pushd `"$escapedItem`"" + "`""
            }
        }
    }
    $argString = $commands -join ';'
    Start-Process "wt.exe" -ArgumentList $argString
    $form.Close()
})

$btnOpenPowershell.Add_Click({
    if ($listBox.Items.Count -eq 0) {
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select at least one path or executable.", "Error", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
        return
    }
    $commands = @()
    foreach ($item in $listBox.Items) {
        $name = Split-Path $item -Leaf
        if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) {
            if ($item.StartsWith("c:\*") -or $item -like "C:\*") {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$name`" $pwsh -NoExit -Command Set-Location `'$item`'"
            } else {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$item`" $pwsh -NoExit -Command `"" + "pushd `"$item`"" + "`""
            }
        } elseif (Test-Path $item -PathType Leaf) {
            $folder = Split-Path $item            
            if ($folder.StartsWith("c:\*") -or $item -like "C:\*") {
                $commands += "new-tab -d `"$folder`" --title `"$name`" $pwsh -NoExit -Command 'cd `"$folder`"' | cls"
            } else {
                $commands += "new-tab --title `"$name`" $pwsh -NoExit -Command `"" + "pushd `"$folder`"" + "`""
            }
        }
    }

    $argString = $commands -join ';'
    Start-Process "wt.exe" -ArgumentList $argString
    $form.Close()
})


$btnCancel.Add_Click({
    $form.Close()
})

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($btnAddPath)
$form.Controls.Add($btnSelectApp)
$form.Controls.Add($btnOpenCmd)
$form.Controls.Add($btnOpenPowershell)
$form.Controls.Add($btnCancel)

[void]$form.ShowDialog()


Keep in mind that once you run the script, you can press Enter and new
form will popup and you can open additional tabs if you need em.
However, only one form can be active.



Closing script will close form, but wont close tabs.
CMD does not support UNC paths. I'm using pushd for CMD UNC connection, it will mount a drive(use popd to dismount while in that CMD tab) or from "This PC" select, right click and dismount.
If you run out of drive letters, script will fail to run


thanks for your response.  I am looking for a script to open an explorer folder with 2 tabs.  I used to do it with a batch script but with the new update to windows 11 that no longer works so I am trying to do it with PowerShell but from what I am coming to find out is that PowerShell doesn't support it.  I was trying to see if anyone had any creative work around ways.  I did get it to work with explorer ++ since that supports it but cannot get normal windows to work with it for the moment.

Yea,...gotta love that unfinished c**p allover the place, from taskbar to explorer itself :D


Since Explorer requires different approach, ill cut it as separate
code
DO NOT touch keyboard or mouse, till script finishes, it uses them, and focus must stay on that explorer or it'll go wild :D
I think it can be saved anywhere and ran from anywhere, all you have to make sure is that your user has access to desired paths(otherwise script needs something bout auth too)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class IconExtractor {
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int ExtractIconEx(string lpszFile, int nIconIndex, IntPtr[] phiconLarge, IntPtr[] phiconSmall, uint nIcons);
}
"@

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$iconPath = "C:\Windows\System32\pifmgr.dll"
$iconIndex = 4
$iconHandle = New-Object IntPtr[] 1
$result = [IconExtractor]::ExtractIconEx($iconPath, $iconIndex, $iconHandle, $null, 1)

if ($result -gt 0 -and $iconHandle[0] -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) {
    $form.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle($iconHandle[0])
}

$form.Text = "Open Paths in Explorer"
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(400, 300)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$listBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(350, 150)
$listBox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20, 20)

$preloadedPaths = @(
    "C:\Program Files",
    "C:\Windows",
    "\\myServerName\a$",
    "\\myServerName\b$"
)
foreach ($path in $preloadedPaths) {
    $listBox.Items.Add($path)
}

$btnAddPath = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnAddPath.Text = "Add Path"
$btnAddPath.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$btnAddPath.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20, 190)

$btnOpenExplorer = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOpenExplorer.Text = "Open in Explorer"
$btnOpenExplorer.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(150, 30)
$btnOpenExplorer.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(130, 190)

$btnCancel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
$btnCancel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$btnCancel.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(290, 190)

$btnAddPath.Add_Click({
    $folderDialog = New-Object Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    if ($folderDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $listBox.Items.Add($folderDialog.SelectedPath)
    }
})

$btnOpenExplorer.Add_Click({
    if ($listBox.Items.Count -eq 0) { return }

    function Simulate-KeyPress {
        param($key, $modifier)
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        public class KeyboardSimulator {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);

            public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;

            public static void PressKey(byte keyCode, byte modifierCode) {
                if (modifierCode != 0) { keybd_event(modifierCode, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero); }
                keybd_event(keyCode, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                keybd_event(keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (modifierCode != 0) { keybd_event(modifierCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, IntPtr.Zero); }
            }
        }
"@
        [KeyboardSimulator]::PressKey($key, $modifier)
    }

    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
    function Open-PathInExplorer {
        param($path, $isFirst)
        if ($isFirst) {
            Simulate-KeyPress 0x45 0x5B
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        } else {
            Simulate-KeyPress 0x54 0x11
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1500
        }
        Simulate-KeyPress 0x4C 0x11
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($path)
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
        Simulate-KeyPress 0x0D
    }

    $isFirst = $true
    foreach ($path in $listBox.Items) {
        Open-PathInExplorer $path $isFirst
        $isFirst = $false
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    }
    $form.Close()
})

$btnCancel.Add_Click({
    $form.Close()
})

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($btnAddPath)
$form.Controls.Add($btnOpenExplorer)
$form.Controls.Add($btnCancel)
[void]$form.ShowDialog()


Hi and thanks for that.  After I add the network folders and ran it it throws up a bunch of red words and closes quickly without giving me a chance to read it

where you had my server right below it a line says add path, am I supposed to add anything there?  If so I have 2 servers to connect to so how would I add them both in 1 line?

When you change paths,...watch for comma's *and quotes.

I just recorded the screen to see the error since it closes within a second and the error has to do with one drive which I don't even see in the code so not sure why its looking for it when the program doesn't even say to look for it.  I added .ps1 to the end of it and changed it to all files and then double click to run it.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I just went to test,...when you copy and paste from here, it adds one tab to each line. Select all and if in notepad++ press Shift+Tab once, should align code properly. Also I removed(just now) that from code above.

@Viper, did you manage to start it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZp4AFT62wA should be pretty simple, just change address.

It started but when it goes to open the folder locations it types the addresses in the search box

I can replicate that only if i open explorer myself, than manually tab it. Otherwise if i run script, after clicking on "open" button, if i dont click anything it opens all paths. When its done I can open as much new ones without issues, works as on video. You can try reducing for ($i = 0; $i -lt 6; $i++) from 6 to 4, but I think it will mess your "next new" tab.

I went and changed it to 4 and also tried 5 and bother of them targeted the refresh button and 6 will target search field.  If I am fast and click in the normal address bar then it will target that and open the 2 folders

changed it to 4.5 and that targeted the correct address bar and worked. Thanks for your help  :)

Hmmm,...funny how lessthen works in that case. I'm glad you made it useful in the end :)

thanks again.  I was also curious as to where I could go to learn more on programming the code like this?  Do you know of any online places to look at that will help teach it?

Not rly, I'm sure there are plenty online. Tho involving something like forms is more on C# then PS side, tho PS is good for load of things ;)

Removed for loop, discovered there is Ctrl+L for it ^^
